# Spree cart not working on Heroku

Tags: heroku, spree

I deployed Spree on Heroku and everything seems to be working correctly except for the shopping cart.

When a user adds a product, the cart is not updated.

I checked the logs and it doesn't shows any errors or warnings.

has anyone dealt with this kind of issues before? Is there any gem I need to install to make this work?

Comment: Spree should run out of the box on Heroku.  I have a Spree 2.0.3 sandbox running on Heroku which doesn't exhibit the issue that you're reporting.  Can you replicate this issue with a fresh install of Spree?

Comment: I haven't been able to replicate it. I installed it on a VPs and everything worked nice.